# Man mistakenly believes that he is in a TV show

Tags: identify-this-movie, comedy

This is a comedy - lead character is male, and I believe it was set in Britain. There exists a TV show (in the fictional world of the movie) where people can set up their friends. The "victim" responds to some "random" event which sets off a scripted series of events which are filmed and designed to provide excitement.

From what I remember: the man answers a phone call, breaks up a fight between a couple in a home, and somehow becomes involved with real criminals whilst believing it is all scripted and part of the show.

I believe this movie was released in the 1990's.

Comment: Last year, but I believe it is from the 1990's.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like [**The Man Who Knew Too Little**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120483/) (1997), starring **Bill Murray**:

> [image: Bill Murray]
>
> An American gets a ticket for an audience participation game in London, then gets involved in a case of mistaken identity. As an international plot unravels around him, he thinks it's all part of the act.

- [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_Who_Knew_Too_Little)
- [Trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2bMmtNRpI8)

Comment: you beat me by 5-10 seconds. +1